# choose oauth2 flow spa application

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, openid, pkce

we are building a full-stack application with a SPA client (reactjs) and a nodejs server which publish resource in an API Rest.

I need to authenticate users with an identity provider like azuread or keycloack.

i want to use the OpenIdConnect protocole (based on Oauth2) but i dont know which flow i need.

I read that Authorisation code with PKCE is the best for SPA but i don’t understand why?
If i obtain an access_token where can i save it in my SPA? is it safe to save this token?

which flow do you recommend for this architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

With OAuth 2.1, its pretty simple.

There are only two flows to choose form:

1. Authorisation code with PKCE when you have a user involved.
2. ClientCredentials flow, when you have machine-to-machine communication without a user involved.

All other flows are no longer recommended.

If you don't want to deal with tokens inside the SPA application, then you can let the backend handle all of it for you, like what this picture shows:

[image]

Between the SPA and backend you have a classic cookie session only.

Comment: So i guess i'm going to implement Authorisation code with PKCE, because there are users on the SPA side.

However, in all examples i seen, its the Client side (SPA) which deals with identity provider, to obtain the access_token, and identity provider redirect to the auth page.

I dont understant, how can i let backend recover access_token ? i need to build a route /login in SPA with a login form, when user click "login" , this call backend /login and at this moment, the backend deal with IP to exchange credentials with access_token ?

Comment: There's a spectrum from doing all the openid-connect in the browser (SPA) to let the backend hide all of it from you. Its also about security and fully understand what is going on. I am personally a bit wary of storing sensitive tokens in the browser and in my suggestion above you keep it all on the server.  see this https://leastprivilege.com/2019/01/18/an-alternative-way-to-secure-spas-with-asp-net-core-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-and-proxykit/